# akka streams, InputStream and binary data

Tags: scala, stream, akka

I'm trying to use akka streams (scala) to read gzipped data streamed from Play's WS client. The data ultimately need to be presented as an InputStream to a legacy API. I'm using akka 2.4.10, so using akka.stream.scaladsl.Compression isn't an option. If I do the following (replacing the Play stuff with a toy app for simplicity; the results in Play are the same):

```
object AkkaTester extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("system")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val filename = "/tmp/helloworld.txt.gz"

  val path = Paths.get(filename)
  val sink = StreamConverters.asInputStream()
  val akkaInput = new GZIPInputStream(FileIO.fromPath(path).runWith(sink))
  var akkaByte = akkaInput.read()
  while (akkaByte != -1) print(akkaByte)
  akkaInput.close()
  system.terminate()
}
```

...then it generates the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: akka.stream.impl.io.InputStreamAdapter.read() returned value out of range -1..255: -117
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(GZIPInputStream.java:272)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort(GZIPInputStream.java:259)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:164)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:79)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:91)
```

I'm new to akka streams, so I'm not sure if this is a bug (the [java docs for InputStream.read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--) clearly state that it should return values in the range of 0..255, so it *feels* like a bug) or just me mis-using akka streams in some way. FWIW, adding 256 to the negative value would give us the value that we would get if we used a straight FileInputStream in place of akka streams.

**UPDATE**
Definitely a bug - the read() method in the relevant code returns a raw, signed byte, meaning it will be in the range -128 to 127 rather than the required 0 to 255. I've [filed an issue](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/21943) on it.